# writeObject and readObject method for a Serializable class which extends ArrayList<E>

Tags: java, collections

I want to extend the ArrayList class to create a collection which doesn't hold duplicate element and use array internally to store. [`SetUniqueList`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/list/SetUniqueList.html) stores unique element, but I want to add more functionality.

I am stuck in the method `writeObject` and `readObject`. This is the implementation in `ArrayList`:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream s) throws java.io.IOException{
    int expectedModCount = modCount;
    s.defaultWriteObject();

    s.writeInt(elementData.length);

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        s.writeObject(elementData[i]);

    if (modCount != expectedModCount) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }

}

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s) throws java.io.IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    s.defaultReadObject();

    int arrayLength = s.readInt();
    Object[] a = elementData = new Object[arrayLength];

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        a[i] = s.readObject();
}
```

Clearly I cannot access `private transient Object[] elementData;`. I am puzzled that should I create class like `ArrayList`, not extending it, or there is any other artcitectural way to do this?

### Update

I need to use `subList` so that changes in the sub list are reflected in this list.

Comment: Couldn't you use an existing implementation of the Set interface? Sets prevent duplicate elements.

Comment: Uh, you can just `Set<X> set = new LinkedHashSet<X>(origList); List<X> list = new ArrayList<X>(set); // serialize list`

Comment: @Funkytown yes I could use that but I need `subList`, so that changes in the sub list are reflected in this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple of ways to implement `readObject` and `writeObject` on a subclass of `ArrayList`:

- Use reflection to call the private methods in `ArrayList` (Nasty!!  But possibly justifiable.).
- Use `super.iterator()` etctera to iterate the elements in your `readObject` method.

---

However, I think you would be better off turning your subclass of `ArrayList` into a wrapper class that delegates operations to a real `ArrayList`.  Just make sure that the wrapper class is `Serializable` and the private variable containing the reference to the wrapped list is not marked as `transient`.)

An `LinkedHashSet` might be another option ... depending on how the collection is used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not understand your first point about the reflection usage. Did you mean I need to call `writeObject` and `readObject` method of the super class `ArrayList` from `writeObject` and `readObject` method of my class? I can't do that. Isn't it?

Comment: @TapasBose - Yes.  That's what I mean.  You >>can<< do it if you use reflection, and the "dirty trick" that allows you to call another classes private methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880365/any-way-to-invoke-a-private-method