# Reflection on Enums

Tags: java, reflection, enums

One of the methods I am currently writing for my Java library takes an array of an arbitrary enumeration type as its sole argument. If any of these is non-null, I can access the instance of `java.lang.Class` representing that enumeration type, which may or may not be a public type. (If they are all null, there is no purpose to this anyway under the circumstances.) How do I get the number of possible values that enumeration type has? The approach I am currently using - `Array.getLength(clazz.getMethod("values").invoke(null));` - fails when the Enum class is not public. How do I fix this?

Comment: does this solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880365/any-way-to-invoke-a-private-method

Comment: @Lynch: Okay, that solved that problem. Now I'm running into a different issue, but I think I can straighten it out from here on my own.

Comment: Can't you do `clazz.getEnumConstants().length`?

Comment: @PaulBoddington: I had forgotten about that method, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: You also need to make sure you do `e.getDeclaringClass()` rather than `e.getClass()`...

Comment: Alright, thanks guys.

Comment: @PaulBoddington: Wouldn't they be equivalent here?

Comment: No, `e.getClass().getEnumConstants()` can return `null`. This is because if an enum has constant-specific method bodies, the constants need individual subclasses.

Comment: @PaulBoddington: Okay. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get an array of enum constants from a `Class` object is

```
clazz.getEnumConstants();
```

To find the number of enum constants you can add `.length` to this.

If you want to get the array of enum constants from an instance of an enum, it is important to do

```
e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants();
```

rather than

```
e.getClass().getEnumConstants();
```

The reason for this is demonstrated by the following example:

```
private enum Colour {
    WHITE,
    BLUE {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "blue";
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Colour.BLUE.getClass().getEnumConstants()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Colour.WHITE.getClass().getEnumConstants()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Colour.BLUE.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants()));
}
```

This program outputs

```
null
[WHITE, blue]
[WHITE, blue]
```

What is going on here is that in order to override the method `toString` for the `BLUE` constant, a subclass of `Colour` is created. This means that `Colour.BLUE.getClass()` does *not* return `Colour.class`, so `Colour.BLUE.getClass().getEnumConstants()` returns `null`. This issue does not apply for `WHITE` because `WHITE` does not require an extra class.

Comment: I know. I pointed it out. I thought it was better as an answer,