# Unhandled exception: NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, exception, reflection, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write my own implementation of the Miller Rabin primality test. 
I could get it working, but it was very slow for values larger than 64 bits.

In the draft standard ANSI X9.80, "PRIME NUMBER GENERATION, PRIMALITY TESTING, AND PRIMALITY CERTIFICATES", they specify behavior up to 1024 bits. My program (on a i7 6700k) would take months at best to run on a single 1024 bit integer.

So I turned to the java implementation of the Miller Rabin test to see what micro-optimizations they used to make the performance tenable.

I've been working my way through their source code, but I've run up against a wall. A lot of the methods they use are private, and testing your codes behavior against code you can't execute is quite difficult.For starters, the first internal method I wanted to call is [BigInteger.mod2( int )](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/math/BigInteger.java#BigInteger.mod2%28int%29)

I've not programmed extensively in java before, but here's where I got stuck:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BigInteger a = new BigInteger( "123456789101112" );
        Method mod2 = BigInteger.class.getDeclaredMethod( "mod2", int.class );
        //Class[] arg_types = new Class[1];
        //arg_types[0] = int.class;
        //Method mod2 = BigInteger.class.getDeclaredMethod( "mod2", arg_types );
        mod2.setAccessible( true );
        Object b = mod2.invoke( a, 32 );
        System.out.print( b );
    }
}
```

Both version of the 'getDeclaredMethod' call throw NoSuchMethodException exceptions. I've looked at the documentation for 'getDeclaredMethod' and they say to do exactly what I'm currently doing when people are asking how to get this function to work.

Any advice on how to invoke the private methods of BigInteger, in particular `BigInteger.mod2( int )` would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Somehow I think you missed the whole point of [private](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/private) methods.

Comment: In what way? I'm trying to write my own implementation of a private method in a java class. I would like to be able to directly call that method in order to compare the output of my code vs. the private method.

Comment: Not only that, but any optimisations you may make by using private methods in places like `BigDecimal` will be negated three times over by your use of reflection.

Comment: I'm writing my own implementation of BigInteger in C. I'm simply trying to figure out how best to compare the output of the respective implementations.

Comment: Then what you should be comparing is the output of the public methods.  After all, the private methods may come and go at any time at Java's sole discretion.  If, in a future upgrade, they decide to rename or otherwise modify this private method, then you're stuffed.

Comment: The output of the public methods is identical. I've already written a full-functional implementation of BigInteger in C. My code is significantly faster than java for simple mathematical operations(add/mult/exp/log/etc). However my code is slower for primality testing, and I'm trying to replicate their optimizations.

However, I am unable to compare outputs because the methods are private.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to Invoke a private method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880365/any-way-to-invoke-a-private-method)

Comment: Your code works for me. Which JDK are you using?

Comment: Is this a compilation error or a runtime exception? The code you posted does not compile. Is that the problem you're asking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track. The only way to invoke private methods in Java is using reflection API. You are already using it. The only error in your program is that you are not handling the checked exception. Just surround your getDeclaredMethod call and method invocation calls with `try-catch` and you are good to go.

```
    BigInteger a = new BigInteger( "123456789101112" );
    Method mod2 = null;
    try {
        mod2 = BigInteger.class.getDeclaredMethod( "mod2", int.class );
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Class[] arg_types = new Class[1];
    //arg_types[0] = int.class;
    //Method mod2 = BigInteger.class.getDeclaredMethod( "mod2", arg_types );
    mod2.setAccessible( true );
    Object b;
    try {
        b = mod2.invoke( a, 32 );
           System.out.print( b );
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Read the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) for the method Class::getDeclaredMethod. It says that this method throws two exceptions (1) NoSuchMethodException and (2) SecurityException.

Same way, read the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) for the method Method::invoke. It says that this method throws three exceptions (1) IllegalAccessException (2)                IllegalArgumentException (3) InvocationTargetException.

The calling method of these methods must catch these exceptions or add a `throws` clause to its own method signature listing out all these exceptions that it is not handling.

Comment: I think this is the right answer. OP doesn't make it clear, but his code doesn't compile, so his actual problem may be an 'unhandled exception' compilation error, and doing this would fix that.

Comment: Or add `throws Exception` at your `main` method. If it's for exploring, there's no harm in doing so. For a real app, avoid it!

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire  yes that option is always there. I have already mentioned that in the last line of my answer. Maybe I need to highlight it. Rather than catching these individual exceptions, the OP can simply add `throws` to his `main` method. However I will not recommend this to someone who is trying to learn java the right way. Once he is comfortable with exception handling, he can use `throws` for quick testing.

Comment: @JacobAsmuth I thought so. A very poorly stated question.

Comment: Yup. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you've failed to handle the checked exceptions that `getDeclaredMethod` may raise. Change the signature to

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
```

After that your code should be working. If `getDeclaredMethod` still raises a `NoSuchMethodException` then there really isn't a `mod2` method in the `BigInteger` that you're linking against.

This will happen if you run against a JDK with a `BigInteger` that doesn't have a method with the signature `private mod2(int)`. Gnu classpath, for example, doesn't have one.

Comment: I wish I could mark both answers correct. I'm basically brand new to java, been a C/C++ guy for years... Didn't realize the extra requirements behind exceptions. The other guy did answer first though so I guess he gets the check mark

Comment: Aye, some days I wish I was still a C guy. A good IDE will take most of the pain out of Java if you have to use it. There are lots of free ones. The intellij community edition is probably the most popular.