# Access to private methods in private class

Tags: java

How can I have access to a private method in a private class?

My code:

```
public class OuterClass {

    private InnerClass ic;

    public OuterClass(){ //Constructor
        this.ic = new InnerClass();
    }

    public InnerClass getInnerClass(){
        return this.ic;
    }

    private class InnerClass {
        private VeryInnerClass vic;

        private void InnerClass(){
            this.vic = new VeryInnerClass();
        }

        private void method(Object item){
            //Job
        }

        private class VeryInnerClass {
            private Object item;

            private void VeryInnerClass(){
                //Constructor
            }

        }//End VeryInnerClass

    }//End InnerClass

}//End OuterClass
```

This is the main code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OuterClass oc = new OuterClass();
        Object item = new Object();

        oc.getInnerClass().method(item);

    }

}
```

The error is that the type OuterClass.InnerClass is not visible, but I used a `getInnerClass()` method, so I don't know how to have access to `method(Object item)`.

Comment: Are you sure you know what `private` means?

Comment: A private method is never accessible from outside of it's owning object. If you want to access `method`, you have to make it public.

Comment: You could invoke it via reflection.

Comment: You can't. You Must make it public or protected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to Invoke a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880365/any-way-to-invoke-a-private-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

> The private modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed in its own class

So, if you want to access to private methods, then you should define them with the `public`, `protected` or *no modifier* depending what is more appropriate in that case.

See more in this [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: `public` is not be required. There's `protected` and no modifier access. Depending on use, one may be more appropriate than the other.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Yes you are right. I will modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't direct access private method / private inner class outside  of the scope of the class.