# Java Reflection NoSuchMethodException when referencing a method in same class

Tags: java, reflection, invoke, nosuchmethod

I am experiencing a NoSuchMethodException when trying to call getMethod on a method in the same class with no arguments from a string name pulled from a hashmap. Any advice, or another way to call a method in the same class given only a String name of the method?
The call to get the method is here:

```
if (testChoices.containsKey(K)) {
        String method = testChoices.get(K);
        System.out.println(method);

        try {
            java.lang.reflect.Method m = TST.getClass().getMethod(method);
            m.invoke(testChoices.getClass());
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("No method found");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();


        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
```

One of the methods I am trying to call is here:

```
private static void testgetDomainLic() throws IOException {
```

And the map entry being called is here:

```
testChoices.put(1, "testgetDomainLic");
```

Comment: Is the static method `testgetDomainLic()` defined in the TST class, or in a superinterface of it?

Comment: TST is just an instance of the class where testgetDomainLic() is.

Comment: I changed it to call the directly defined class with Class.forName and it still is not finding the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case you can just change [`getMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) to [`getDeclaredMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-). `getMethod` only returns public methods.

The hiccup here is that they actually have different semantics *other* than whether or not they return non-public methods. `getDeclaredMethod` only includes methods which are *declared* and not *inherited*.

So for example:

```
class Foo { protected void m() {} }
class Bar extends Foo {}
Foo actuallyBar = new Bar();
// This will throw NoSuchMethodException
// because m() is declared by Foo, not Bar:
actuallyBar.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("m");
```

In the worst case like this, you have to loop through all declared methods, like this:

```
Class<?> c = obj.getClass();
do {
    for (Method m : c.getDeclaredMethods())
        if (isAMatch(m))
            return m;
} while ((c = c.getSuperclass()) != null);
```

Or accounting for interfaces (mostly because they can declare static methods now):

```
List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<>();
for (Class<?> c = obj.getClass(); c != null; c = c.getSuperclass())
    classes.add(c);
Collections.addAll(classes, obj.getClass().getInterfaces());
Method m = classes.stream()
                  .map(Class::getDeclaredMethods)
                  .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                  .filter(this::isAMatch)
                  .findFirst()
                  .orElse(null);
```

And as a side note, you probably *don't* need to call `m.setAccessible(true)`, because you're invoking it from within the class that declares it. This is necessary, though, in other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but try changing your method so it is not private.

Private methods can be invoked by reflection, but there are extra steps. See [Any way to Invoke a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880365/any-way-to-invoke-a-private-method)

Comment: The OP is getting a NoSuchMethodException. The problem is with `getMethod()` -- not with `invoke()`.

Comment: Also, I have tried removing the Private but it still gives the same error

Comment: OK. So I'm fixing the problem they haven't got to yet!