# How can you access a private method with dependency injection in a Spring app?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Using the @Autowired annotation, I've managed to succesfully call the methods i needed from another class, however not all of them, since some methods are private.

Is it possible to call them without making them public? How?

Comment: see using reflection possible but not recommended. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880365/any-way-to-invoke-a-private-method

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Dependency injection is just a trick, that takes handling of interfaces and implementations from developer. Framework is doing that for you. The resulting object has same properties as if it was created using `new` keyword.

Comment: So the only way to access them is to make them public in the original class? Could i use reflection or other techniques?