# Issue in writing junit test case for NullPointerException for private methods

Tags: java, junit, reflection, private-methods

The function template is

```
private static void processTextFile(String iFile, String tmpDirLoc, String tmpDrive, String iMode)
```

I want to test for NullPointerException in case when iFile is null.
Since the original method processTextFile is Private in nature, so I am using reflection in my test case to access the method but I can't write the test case for AssertThrows condition.
please help me writing this.

this is my code

```
    @Test()
    public void TC1_processTextFileTest() {
    Method method = crashParser.class.getDeclaredMethod("left",String.class,int.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    crashParser cp = new crashParser();
    String ifile=null;
    //cp.processTextFile(ifile,null,null,null);
    //NullPointerException ex= assertThrows(NullPointerException.class,()-> 
   //cp.processTextFile(ifile,null,null,null));
    //assertEquals("Array can't be null",ex.getMessage());
   }
```

Comment: It always left me confused why people think they should test private methods...

Comment: Really what you are asking is how to call an inaccessible private method using reflection; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880365/any-way-to-invoke-a-private-method

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing a Unit test for a private method, instead reference the public object or method that utilizes that private method to assert that some internal state is as intended.